# Problem submitting form in XML format - Can we submit it in CSV format?

Tags: usaidopen

We registered a dataset on the [Development Data Library (DDL)](https://www.usaid.gov/data) website, and in the form we said that we planned to submit it in XML format, but we are having problems converting the dataset to XML.  Can we submit it in CSV format?  Do we need to resubmit the form?

Comment: What is "the DDL website"?

Comment: @aventurin https://www.usaid.gov/data

Answer (score 3):

The Office of Management and Budget (OMB) [Open Data Policy (M-13-13)](https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/memoranda/2013/m-13-13.pdf) states that to make data accessible to everyone, “formats should be non-proprietary, publicly available, and no restrictions should be placed upon their use.”  As the “CSV” format is non-proprietary and usable in most spreadsheet and statistical software packages, it meets this criterion and is a valid way to submit data to the Development Data Library.

If you have already completed the [DDL submission form](https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/memoranda/2013/m-13-13.pdf), you will receive an email response with further instructions on how to upload your data.  You can include the CSV at that time. You would not need to resubmit the form. Specific questions on your submission can also be directed to opendata@usaid.gov.